# stateful session bean and remove() method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE **stateful session bean:**

```
@Stateful(passivationCapable=false)
public class Session {

@Inject
private Services services;

private Item item;
private List<Item> items;

..

@Remove
public void remove() { 
// do I have to make this manually? 
// Or will the container set this automatically to null after `remove` is called?
item = null;
items = null;
services = null;
}
}
```

The `remove()`-method sets the instance properties of `Session` to `null`.

**Do I have to make this manually? Or will the container set this automatically to null after `remove` is called?**

Comment: The instance of your Session class will disappear afer `remove()` method is called. No need to set the members variables to null. You would have, however, to close a connection or such if you did open one.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. I will accept this as anwer..